# Rackmount server case, equipment to mount on multiple rails

Tags: rackmount, hardware

Right then we've got a massive rack cabinet in our server room, it currently houses a few large servers and a giant UPS, the servers are very large so are supported by the rails at the front and rear of the cabinet, I believe they're on sliders.

I want to add another server to the cabinet, this time a 1U (perhaps a 2U at a stretch), I've looked at our old smaller cabinet and our gigabit netgear switch which is being hung by it's 'ears' is sagging quite a bit.

So here's my question, If I was looking at getting a [rackmount case like this](http://www.xcase.co.uk/X-Case-RM100-E-1U-black-p/case-x-case-rm100e.htm), what would I need to hang it by the rails at the back and front of the cabinet.

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> X-Case RM100-E 1U black ATX Dual Xeon
>   Server Rackmount Chassis **with rail kit**
>   and 4 cooling fans -

That server should include rails; most rails attach to the front and back posts in the rack, the server slides in so the server should be fully supported.

You could get a rack-mountable 'table' (for lack of a better description) for the switch.

Comment: Good catch with the rail kit :) 
Depending on the size and especially the weight of the switch, this hanging down is ok. If not, I prefer generic mounting rails, as they don't need 1U of space by themselves.

Comment: Ah right I understand, so it should everything to hang it up at both ends :D cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First, if you can put the server directly on top of one of the large servers, it's OK to let the 1U server lean on the big one a bit. This way, a front mount is enough.

Other than that, you need mounting rails for this case. They should come with the case even if they are not listed, but you should check that.

These rails will be fixed to the side of the case and in most cases, they can be used to pull the server half out of the rack to service it.

Two other alternative are "generic" mounting rails (basically two L shaped metal pieces fixed on the front and the back of the rack) or shelve boards for the rack. The latter have the problem that they will eat 1U of space by themselve.

Comment: No, it's not OK at all. Maintenance on the 1U server involves risking breaking your legs if you pull it out too far, and the "big server" below the 1U could possibly be harder to maintenance if the 1U server grabs something while pulling it out.

Comment: Of course you are right and I should have put that option last instead  of first, but nevertheless, if you know what you are doing, I still consider it acceptable when having no other option.